# Cannot read property 'useState' of null - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forge

I am trying to create a simple CountDown application using React and Forge. Here is my code:

```
import ForgeUI, { Button, Form, FormLayout, TextField } from '@forge/ui';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const runView = () => {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(0);

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newCountdown = parseInt(event.target.countdown.value, 10);
    setCountdown(newCountdown);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <FormLayout>
        <TextField name="countdown" type="number" label="Countdown (in seconds)" />
        <Button type="submit">Start Countdown</Button>
        {countdown !== 0 && (
          <p>
            Time remaining: {countdown}
          </p>
        )}
      </FormLayout>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Do you have any ideas why I keep getting this error ?

Comment: Your component should be with an uppercase letter

Comment: Please, can you explain more ?

Comment: You should write RunView.

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting but this is not the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace. Which line of code does it refer to? Please also include the dependencies part of `package.json` so we can see which version of React you're using. As it stands, this is not reproducible

Comment: That does seem to be the issue.  see https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized "React Hook "useState" is called in function "runView" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)" - eslint

Comment: Naming component runview just renders "<runview></runview>" to html without even calling your component.

Comment: So do you suggest creating a function inside the runView ?